# algorithm2e fully justified input / output blocks

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I would like to fully justify the input/output blocks in the `algorithm2e` environment. How can this be achieved?

I cannot find anything regarding this matter in the documentation. To be precise, I would like to keep the indentation as it is, just have the text block fully justified. (I tried just using `ragged2e` and simply putting `\justify` in the beginning of the input contents, but that did weird things.)

MWE (ignore the algorithm):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[algoruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Getting things done}
    \Input{Many things with longish names that make the ragged right look ugly in my opinion. Many things with longish names that make the ragged right look ugly in my opinion. Many things with longish names that make the ragged right look ugly in my opinion.}
    \For{$k=1$ \KwTo $N$}{
        \tcp{Do something}
        $x_k^- = A_{k-1} x_{k-1}^+ + B_{k-1} u_{k-1}$ \;
        $P_{k}^- = A_{k-1} P_{k-1}^+ A_{k-1}^T + Q_{k-1}$ \;
        \tcp{And now do something else}
        $K_k = P_{k}^- C_k^T (C_k P_{k}^- C_k^T + R_{k})^{-1}$ \;
        $x_{k}^+ = x_{k}^- + K_{k}(y_{k}-C_k x_{k}^-)$ \;
        $P_{k}^+ = (I - K_{k} C_k) P_{k}^-$ \;
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To be a bit more specific, `\Input{\justify Text...}` introduces a line break after "Input:" and also removes the indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[algoruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\SetKwInOut
  {\hangafter=1\parbox[t]}
  {\hangafter=1\justify\parbox[t]}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Getting things done}
    \Input{Many things with longish names that make the ragged right look ugly in my opinion. Many things with longish names that make the ragged right look ugly in my opinion. Many things with longish names that make the ragged right look ugly in my opinion.}
    \For{$k=1$ \KwTo $N$}{
        \tcp{Do something}
        $x_k^- = A_{k-1} x_{k-1}^+ + B_{k-1} u_{k-1}$ \;
        $P_{k}^- = A_{k-1} P_{k-1}^+ A_{k-1}^T + Q_{k-1}$ \;
        \tcp{And now do something else}
        $K_k = P_{k}^- C_k^T (C_k P_{k}^- C_k^T + R_{k})^{-1}$ \;
        $x_{k}^+ = x_{k}^- + K_{k}(y_{k}-C_k x_{k}^-)$ \;
        $P_{k}^+ = (I - K_{k} C_k) P_{k}^-$ \;
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some explanations:

When calling `\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}`, it defines `\Input` by

```
% here #1 is first arg of \SetKwInOut, here it is "Input"
\algocf@newcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@hanginginout}}{\relax}{\algocf@seteveryparhanging{\relax}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@inoutnumbered}}{\relax}{\algocf@seteveryparnl{\relax}}%
    % The following line control the output of \Input{##1}.
    % This paragraph starts at \parbox, hence the change of paragraph
    % indent (\justify) should be inserted before \parbox.
    {\let\\\algocf@newinout\hangindent=\inoutindent\hangafter=1\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo\hfill:}}~##1\par}%
    \algocf@linesnumbered% reset the numbering of the lines
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@hanginginout}}{\relax}{\algocf@reseteveryparhanging}%
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! Can you briefly comment on how you come up with such an answer, e.g., what's the solution process? You look inside the source code of the package and search for `\SetKwInOut` and then attempt to figure out what's going on? And that call to `\xpatchcmd` does something like search & replace in the command definition?

Comment: @jhin Firstly I searched for `\Input` and `input` in `algorithms2e.sty`, then I found `\algocf@inoutbox` and `\algocf@inputbox`. This led me to the definition of `\SetKwInOut` and `\SetKwInput`, which shows how the hang-indent of keyword is implemented. Combining with the `\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}` you used and with some attempts, I got the final solution. And yes, `\xpatchcmd`, provided by `xpatch` package, does something like search & replace. It saves space if the full definition is long.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! Maybe, at some point, I'll be able to come up with these things myself...

Comment: @jhin Actually, I should have noticed `\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}` before searching in `algorithms2e.sty`.