# Algorithm2e: Width of algorithm rules and text alignment

Tags: rules, alignment, algorithm2e

I have two questions linked to the algorithms environment that I am using in LaTeX.

## Example

Let me start with an example file to illustrate what I'm looking for. Algorithm 1 in the MWE below does what I want: It spans 95% of the text width, is centered, has rules of that width, and indentation is the way I want it to be, as in the image below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%% Memoir layout setup
%\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
%\setlrmarginsandblock{2.25cm}{2.25cm}{*}
%\checkandfixthelayout

%% packages
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% algorithm environment
\usepackage[vlined,ruled,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\setlength{\algoheightrule}{1pt}
\setlength{\algotitleheightrule}{0.7pt}
\newcommand{\marginwidth}{0.025\linewidth}
\newcommand{\algoboxwidth}{0.95\linewidth}
\setlength{\algomargin}{0.0em}
\SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{0.95\linewidth}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@algocf@start}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
}{%
  \rule{\marginwidth}{\z@}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\algoboxwidth}%
}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@algocf@finish}{%
  \end{lrbox}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
}{}{}
% extend caption all the way to the right
\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption@ruled}[2]{%
  \global\sbox\algocf@capbox{\hskip\AlCapHSkip%
    \setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}% restored on exit of sbox
    \addtolength{\hsize}{-2\AlCapHSkip}% add equal margin to both sides
    \vtop{\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}}% then caption is not centered
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm2e}[H]
\caption{A simple algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\Input{Give me some input.}
\smallskip
\ForEach{outer iteration}{
\ForEach{inner iteration}{
calculate some cool stuff
}
more cool stuff
}
\Return{got it}
\end{algorithm2e}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm2e}[H]
\caption{This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption.}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\Input{\lipsum[2]}
\smallskip
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0.3em, labelwidth=0.9em, leftmargin=!, topsep=0pt]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{algorithm2e}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

## Issues

1. Note that the layout setup, i.e., the three lines

   ```
   \setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
   \setlrmarginsandblock{2.25cm}{2.25cm}{*}
   \checkandfixthelayout
   ```

   is commented out in the above document. If that setup is used, the lines bounding the algorithms don't extend to 95% of the line width any longer. I can, of course, fiddle around with the factor in `\SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{0.95\linewidth}`, but I guess there should be a general solution to this problem that really gives me 95% of the linewidth.

   Also, I would be happy to understand why the behaviour is not as expected.

   The picture below shows the situation.

   [image]
2. In Algorithm 2, where we have more text in the caption, input, and algorithm body, there are two points I don't like:

   - *Text width*: The caption is corrected manually to take the full algorithm width, how can I do this for the input, as well? The algorithm body seems to have the correct width.
   - *Text alignment*: Is there a way to justify both the input and the algorithm body text?
     I tried the suggestion at [algorithm2e fully justified input / output blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555396/algorithm2e-fully-justified-input-output-blocks) for the Input, but for some reason that I do not understand, this introduces extra spacing above the input in my case.

   Again, the picture below shows how things look like.

   [image]

Comment: I am still looking for a solution. Any ideas/suggestions (also partial ones are appreciated!) anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Some analysis for you: using the `enumerate` environment inside the `algorithm2e` (floating) environment seems to destroy normal alignment, see e.g. in this [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures).

Compare:

- normal `enumerate` environment
- `enumerate` environment inside an `algorithm2e` environment

[image: 2 enumerate environments]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item \blindtext
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{algorithm2e}[H]
        \caption{some enum in algo}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item \blindtext
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{algorithm2e}
\end{document}
```

Which increases my suspicion of using enumerations inside an algorithm: what shall that mean? What kind of action is the algorithm performing there?

**Suggestion**: use some crisp action-statements INSIDE the algo (like `plotting(thingies);`), AND explain in more detail later (`plotting(thingies)` is a complicated process, which involves this and that ...) , if it's that what you want.

**P.S.**: If you insist on enum inside, try a `\parbox`, e.g. like this, where I don't know if it may have side-effects:

[image: enum with parbox]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item \blindtext
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{algorithm2e}[H]
        \caption{some enum in algo}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item \blindtext
          \item \parbox[t]{8cm}{\blindtext}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{algorithm2e}
\end{document}
```